# Missing data while Laravel create()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I try create new post using:

```
$post = $this->post->create($session, $response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID']);
```

In `$session` are complete array of data for store.
In `$response['PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID']` is token of payment.

When I check database, some fields are missing, but all data are in `$session`.

Why `create()` in Laravel don't want store all data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with editing Eloquent. No issue with code.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the field names in

```
protected $fillable = ['field1','field2','field3'];
```

in your Eloquent Model